Switch to Admin consent Workflow in Azure
in my azure tenant currently I have the default option of "allow users consent for apps" in the consent permission settings. I now want to switch and select either "do no allow user consent" or "allow user consent for apps from verified publishers" and use the admin workflow for having users quickly request consent to the admins. My question is: What will happen to all the app registrations in my tenant that have been granted consents from users? Will i need to re-give consent with admin or not?
I try to look on azure documentation but i did not find anything explicit regarding this

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application:

Now I set the consent permissions setting as default:

Signed in with the user successfully:


Note that: The user consented already to the applications doesn't require consent with admin again.

Now I set the consent permissions setting as "Do not allow user consent"

And logged in with same user and the user logged in without any issue:

When I tried to login with another user got error like below:

Hence you can set Admin consent requests as YES:

User will be directed to Approval required screen and can request the admin to approve the access:

